# Python list.append function changes previous added member unexpectedly

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm facing an issue with python as below:

- I have 2 initial lists:

first_list = [['a1', 'a2'], ['a1', 'a2']]

second_list = ['b1', 'b2']

- I want to replace "b2" in second_list by each of value from another list, then add it to first_list. For example:

parts = ['C', 'D']

My expected result for first_list will be: [['a1', 'a2'], ['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'C'], ['b1', 'D']]

Here is my code:

```
first_list = [['a1','a2'], ['a1','a2']]
second_list = ['b1','b2']

parts = ['C', 'D']

for record in parts:
    print record    #print to see which value we will use to replace "b2"
    temp = second_list
    temp[1] = record
    print temp      #print to see which value will be appended to first_list
    first_list.append(temp)
    print first_list     #print first_list after adding a new member
```

And the result is:

```
C
['b1', 'C']
[['a1', 'a2'], ['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'C']]
D
['b1', 'D']
[['a1', 'a2'], ['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'D'], ['b1', 'D']]
```

I suspect that something is wrong but can't explain it. Replacing "append" by "insert" function still shows the same issue. Could someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the thing is that you copy just reference in this step `temp = second_list`

so the `temp` is actually the same thing as `second_list`

you have to copy the values which you can do for example like this `temp = second_list[:]` it will create new list and it should work

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Fixed. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Every time you just update the same list(temp).
To get expected behavior all you need to do is maintain a new copy of the list.

```
for record in parts:
    print record    #print to see which value we will use to replace "b2"
    temp = second_list[:]  #make a new copy
    temp[1] = record
    print temp      #print to see which value will be appended to first_list
    first_list.append(temp)
    print first_list     #print first_list after adding a new member
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :-)

Comment: What about for a dictionary? Do you just wrap the dictionary in dict() to create a new instance? for example....... temp = dict(second_dict)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you append the same 'temp' list twice to 'first_list'. You can use:

https://pypi.org/project/memory-graph/

to make a graph of your data to better understand the Python Data Model and what data is shared among your variables. This is the graph after the first loop:

[image]

and this after the second loop:

[image]

The third and fourth list in 'first_list' is the same list. If this doesn't help it will be much clearer if you yourself graph each intermediate step. As suggested by others, you probably want 'temp' to be a copy of 'second_list' and not a reference to avoid sharing the data. That gives what you expected:

```
import memory_graph # see install instructions at link above

first_list = [['a1','a2'], ['a1','a2']]
second_list = ['b1','b2']

parts = ['C', 'D']

for record in parts:
    print(record)    #print to see which value we will use to replace "b2"
    temp = second_list.copy() # <-------- copy
    temp[1] = record
    print(temp)      #print to see which value will be appended to first_list
    first_list.append(temp)
    print(first_list)     #print first_list after adding a new member

memory_graph.d() # draw graph
```

[image]

Full disclosure: I am the developer of [memory_graph](https://pypi.org/project/memory-graph/).

Comment: Nice module, by the way!

Comment: Thanks. I think the module can be very helpful for beginners to understand the Python Data Model. If beginners misunderstand it they tend to get bugs that take a very long time to solve. Printing doesn't help them as that will not show what data is shared. Making a graph with 'memory_graph' does show.